# Location of urls.py in Zinnia for Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, zinnia

I'm trying to use the Zinnia app in Django. My question where is 'urls.py' in

```
url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
```

I've search but can not find it. Or does it mean find all url files inside Zinnia app not just one named urls.py

Comment: That line should go into the main `urls.py` of the Django instance.

Comment: Yes but where is Zinnia's urls.py?

Comment: Have you tried looking for it in [the apps code](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia)?

Comment: I saw urls in the urls directory under site-packages/zinnia, but how does zinnia.urls point to those url files?

Comment: Look at `__init__.py` in that directory - [here's an SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/4974980) on what the file does.